# Table Cycling for Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a powershell script that I want to read a value (VALUE1) from an excel table (I can convert it to XML if necessary), assign it to a variable($PLACEHOLDER), run the rest of the script, then loop back to the beginning, but instead of reading the original value(VALUE1) I want it to read the value below it(VALUE2) and overwrite $PLACEHOLDER with VALUE2, then re-run the script until it returns a blank value, then I want it to stop. I am insanely new to powershell and it's interaction with excel/xml, so any help would be greatly appreciated. (I'm self-taught, so I don't know TOO much about parameters)

```
Sample in Terrible Psuedo:
#Initial placeholder value here
$RowNumber = 0
#Start of the loop here, add one to previous value
$RowNumber +1
#Call the value in Column (1), Row ($RowNumber), and assign it to $RowValue
?????? = $RowValue
#Execute the command involving the data value
ECHO "C:/test/temporary/$RowValue"
#Goto the start of the loop.
```

If you could be so kind, would you please give a quick explanation of the functions that you use (Parameters, what's happening, ect.)

EDIT: If it could detect and skip over blank rows, that would be amazing.

EDIT3: Code for Ansgar

```
$xl = New-Object -COM 'Excel.Application'
$xl.Visible = $true   # set to $false for production

$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\xe474109\Desktop\EXCEL FILES\testbook2.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)

$row = $ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
while ( $ws.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value -ne $null ) {
  $PLACEHOLDER = $ws.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value

  #
  # do stuff with $PLACEHOLDER here
  #(I wanted to test this by just printing the $PLACEHOLDER value
  $PLACEHOLDER

  $row++
} 

$wb.Close()
$xl.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
```

Comment: can you save your excel file as a csv file?  if you can powershell may be able to do the processing very easily

Comment: Are there any special things I have to do to the excel file to save it as csv? Or can I just change the extension? (I know it's not a true conversion, but my excel doesn't have the option to export as CSV)

Comment: the "save as" on excel should allow you to save as csv

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me. I'm running XP with Office 2010. If I change the extension it seems to open a function spreadsheet though. Sorry if I am not being much help.

Comment: don't change the extension when you do a save as, change the "save as type" to CSV (MS-DOS)

Comment: Nevermind, I'm dumb, there's a scrollbar next to the "Save as Type" dropdown. Sorry for the confusion. I still don't understand how/what code I should be using.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Excel installed? If so, you can process Excel spreadsheets like this:

```
$xl = New-Object -COM 'Excel.Application'
$xl.Visible = $true   # set to $false for production

$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open('C:\path\to\your.xlsx')
$ws = $wb.Sheets.Item(1)

$row = $ws.UsedRange.Row
while ( $ws.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value -ne $null ) {
  $PLACEHOLDER = $ws.Cells.Item($row, 1).Value

  #
  # do stuff with $PLACEHOLDER here
  #

  $row++
} 

$wb.Close()
$xl.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
```

Comment: I tried to just check the value of $Placeholder as it loops, and it just seems to store the following:

`IsSettable          : True
IsGettable          : True
OverloadDefinitions : {Variant Value (Variant)}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Object
MemberType          : ParameterizedProperty
Value               : Variant Value (Variant) {get} {set} 
Name                : Value
IsInstance          : True`

Comment: It didn't when I tested it. Please show your code. Don't post it in a comment (that would be unreadable). Update your question instead.

Comment: @Kain I said show your **code**. If I had meant "output" I would've said so.

Comment: @Kain For one thing: `$row = $ws.UsedRange.Row`, not `$row = $ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count`. That doesn't explain the weird output you're getting, though. What are the actual values in that column in your Excel sheet?

Answer (score 0):

```
cls

$csv = Import-csv -Path 'C:\test\csvStuff.csv'

foreach ($rec in $csv) {
  if ($rec.nameofyourcolumn -ne '') {
    & "c:\test\temporary\$($rec.nameofyourcolumn)"
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to return any meaningful value, it hangs on unrecognized cmdlet c:\test\temporary